# Setting the value of a property in sql table

Tags: orientdb

I know it is really basic question. I want to add a property to a table.
The command I user was :

```
ADD PROPERTY node.total_calls IF NOT EXIST INTEGER
```

I can see the property being added but there is no initialized value for the property, In fact I want to set the property to have the value of one other property(called failure) at the initialization, Is there any command to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you can use DEFAULT for this purpose

Comment: How would be the command?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

I should use the update table afterward to set the value.